# Binding Slider value property to one of two class properties - depending on combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a problem with binding properties.
I have combobox, 4 textboxes, a slider and a class with 4 decimal properties - every property is binded to one textbox. But I have a problem with a slider - depending on combobox I want the slider to be binded to second or fourth property. 
Every time I needed binding until now, I could easily do it in XAML, however this time I don't think it's possible.

Ok, so my class [EDITED]:

```
class Joint : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private decimal _alfa;
        public decimal alfa
        {
            get { return _alfa; }
            set { _alfa = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        private decimal _l;
        public decimal l
        {
            get { return _l; }
            set { _l = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
        }
        private decimal _lambda;
        public decimal lambda
        {
            get { return _lambda; }
            set { _lambda = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
        }
        private decimal _theta;
        public decimal theta 
        {
            get { return _theta; }
            set { _theta = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
        }
        private decimal _min;
        public decimal min
        {
            get { return _min; }
            set { _min = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
        }
        private decimal _max;
        public decimal max
        {
            get { return _max; }
            set { _max = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        private TypeOfJoints _type;
        public TypeOfJoints type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
        }


        public Joint()
        {
            alfa = 1.00M;
            l = 2.00M;
            lambda = 3.00M;
            theta = 140.00M;
            min = -200.00M;
            max = 200.00M;
            type = TypeOfJoints.Rotary;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
                propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

My enum[EDITED]:

```
enum TypeOfJoints
    {
        Rotary,
        Sliding,
    }
```

And the part of my XAML code[EDITED]:

```
<GroupBox Header="Joint 1">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=joint1}">
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding type, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource JointEnum}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding alfa, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding l, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding lambda, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding theta, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Slider x:Name="slider1" Minimum="{Binding min}" Maximum="{Binding max}" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged">
            <Slider.Resources>
                <local:SliderValueConverter x:Key="SliderValueConverter" />
            </Slider.Resources>
            <Slider.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SliderValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="type"/>
                    <Binding Path="lambda"/>
                    <Binding Path="theta"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Slider.Value>
        </Slider>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

And the Validator class:

```
class SliderValueConverter :IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        TypeOfJoints type = (TypeOfJoints)values.FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(type);
        if (type == TypeOfJoints.Sliding)
                return values.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
        else if (type == TypeOfJoints.Rotary)
                return values.ElementAtOrDefault(2);

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So now the slider value is binded to property "fourth", but instead, I want this binding to be dependent on ComboBox value - there are two possible: Second and Fourth - the Fourth is the starting value, that's why now I have static binding to property fourth. But I want it to change to value second when the ComboBox value will change.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good usage for [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx).  Set it up like this:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider1" Minimum="{Binding min}" Maximum=" {Binding max}" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged">
    <Slider.Resources>
        <local:SliderValueConverter x:Key="SliderValueConverter" />
    </Slider.Resources>
    <Slider.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SliderValueConverter}">
            <Binding Path="type" />
            <Binding Path="second" />
            <Binding Path="fourth" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Slider.Value>
</Slider>
```

Note: make sure to use TwoWay binding for ComboBox.SelectedValue so that the view model property will update:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding type,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NumberEnum}}"/>
```

Lastly, implement SliderValueConverter as an [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx), and return the appropriate value.

```
public class SliderValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    { 
        vartype = values.FirstOrDefault() as TypeOfJoints?;
        decimal? val1 = values.ElementAtOrDefault(1) as decimal?,
                 val2 = values.ElementAtOrDefault(2) as decimal?;
        if (type.HasValue && val1.HasValue && val2.HasValue)
        {
            if (type.Value == TypeOfJoints.Sliding)
                return val1.Value;
            else if (type.Value == TypeOfJoints.Rotary)
                return val2.Value
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;      // no match - return default;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Another problem: for bindings from a view model source to update, the view model must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event as appropriate.  In this case, we would need:

```
class Joint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public decimal first 
    { 
        get { return _first; }
        set { _first = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private decimal _first;

    // and so forth with the other properties ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
            propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: When I use your solution, it doesn't work at all, and when I try to move my slider I got an error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred`. It's probably because of this unimplemented method ConvertBack, but I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: @Dess I guess the reason it doesn't work, is that you're not raising "PropertyChanged" in your property setters.

Comment: @Dess for the "NotImplementedException", I guess you are using a two-way binding on the slider?  If that's the case, then you'll have to code "ConvertBack" -- just take the value (the slider value), and return the new values as appropriate for "type", "second", and "fourth".

Comment: If you mean `mode=TwoWay`, than no, I'm not using that :/ I edited my Joint class, is that what you meant by PropertyChanged in your comment? I am really clueless with this, it's all new to me;p

Comment: @Dess that's the right idea, but you also need to use `Joint : INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise the event in your setters (can't use auto-implemented properties for this).  See my edited answer for an example.

Comment: I added everything you told me, but still not working:/ I updated code in my post. And edited naming so it would be more accurate to what I was doing.

Comment: @Dess what is the type of "JointEnum"?  You'll have to tweak the implementation of "SliderValueConverter" accordingly (ie, the first item in `values` will match that item type).

Comment: JointEnum has type TypeOfJoints, my enum included in post above. I edited SliderValueConverter, but don't know if correctly, still not working;p

Comment: @Dess you probably have to add more checks in the converter (see my update above).  I have no idea if there are other problems: I can only suggest to check the Output window, add breakpoints/watches ...